# Eliminar cadenas repetidas

Tags: c, archivo

Pregunto por curiosidad,en un fichero se puede eliminar cadenas si se repiten ? He estado viendo ejemplos en internet y prácticamente todos leen carácter a carácter ? No se puede directamente leyendo la cadena sin necesidad de ir carácter a carácter o es menos optimo? Porque en un fichero quizas tengo dos palabras **pedro pedro** y cuando quiero pasarlo a otro fichero solo quiero que me aparezca una cadena que sea pedro sin repetirse. Simplemente quiero saber que es lo más óptimo.

Comment: No. Los archivos son secuencias de datos escritas en disco, no puedes eliminar datos arbitrariamente, tienes que 1) leer el archivo completo 2) modificar los datos 3) re-escribir el archivo.

Comment: Exactamente, ¿ Que estás preguntando ? ¿ Si se pueden eliminar cadenas repetidas ? ¿ Si se puede leer mas de un carácter ? ¿ Si es mas óptimo leer caracteres individuales que bloques de ellos ? ¿ En que contexto ? ¿ Con qué código ? Por favor, consulta lo que es un [mcve] y también [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster me ha entendido, basicamente de un fichero con varios datos repetidos al pasarlo a otro nuevo ya no deben estar repetidos. Y si la mejor manera de hacerlo es leer caracter a caracter e ir comparando si son iguales y no meterlo en el nuevo fichero o si hay una manera de leer la cadena entera y extraerlo de esa manera.

Comment: No se trata de que yo te entienda o no. Se trata de formular correctamente una pregunta. Consulta por favor los enlaces que te he proporcionado, además de esta publicación en meta: [¿ Porqué he recibido un voto negativo ?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/19610). Un saludo.

Comment: A nivel de hardware se leen sectores completos (512 a 4.096 bytes tipicamente) a memoria (al por mayor, diriamos). Desde ese buffer se lee de a pedacitos (al por menor) cada vez que lees una variable o una línea.

Answer (score 3):

> en un fichero se puede eliminar cadenas si se repiten ?

en el fichero como tal no, debes leer el fichero, es decir, moverlo a la memoria del sistema. Allí lo manipulas a tu antojo para, finalmente, reemplazar el archivo original con lo que hayas obtenido.

> No se puede directamente leyendo la cadena sin necesidad de ir carácter a carácter o es menos optimo?

Un archivo no es más que una secuencia de bytes. Esos bytes son, directamente, contenido binario. Algunos archivos limitan el rango de valores que puede tener cada byte a aquellos valores que representan caracteres, números, signos de puntuación ... estos archivos pueden ser interpretados directamente por el ser humano y son los que pueden leerse en modo texto.

Dicho de otra forma ... el sentido que tu le das a una palabra no existe para un archivo. No hay una estructura de datos especial que delimite las palabras. Son simplemente secuencias de bytes a las que tu, como ser humano, les das un sentido.

Por otro lado, piensa que tu programa está al final de una cadena que, muy simplificada, podría lucir así:

- En el disco duro, la información se almacena en bloques, de tal manera que un archivo cualquiera puede ocupar uno o varios bloques.
- Al leer un archivo, el sistema operativo se encarga de ir moviendo esos bloques a la memoria RAM.
- Cuando tu programa vaya a consultar alguno de esos bloques, el Sistema Opertivo debe mover dicho bloque (o una parte del mismo) a la memoria caché.
- Finalmente tu programa procesará el contenido de la memoria caché.

Así pues, como ves, los archivos no se leen realmente caracter a caracter sino que se leen por fragmentos. Es tu programa el que se limita a pedir caracter a caracter ... pero también podrías pedir el archivo por bloques más grandes. Eso sí, en ese caso te tocaría interpretar esos bloques para saber dónde empieza y dónde acaba cada palabra y esto, normalmente, se hace procesando el bloque caracter a caracter ... así que estamos en las mismas.

> Simplemente quiero saber que es lo más óptimo.

Tu duda no tiene una respuesta concreta, porque ... ¿En qué nos basamos para saber que es óptimo?

- ¿En el tiempo que tarda el programa en ejecutarse?
- ¿En el tiempo que se invierte en leer el archivo?
- ¿El consumo total de memoria quizás?
- ¿En el número de operaciones de I/O?
- ¿?

Si, por ejemplo analizásemos el tiempo de ejecución para obtener el valor óptimo, entonces tendríamos que ver qué tamaño suelen tener los archivos ... no es lo mismo procesar archivos de 100KB que archivos de 100TB.

En cualquier caso, también hay que tener en cuenta otros factores, es decir, suponiendo que volviesemos a elegir el tiempo de ejecución como elemento a minimizar, llegará un momento en el que el coste de seguir mejorando imponga peajes excesivos en otros aspectos:

- Un código super-optimizado es facil que sea ilegible
- Un código super-optimizado puede aprovechar características propias del sistema en el que se ejecuta, resultando un código que no será portable
- Otros parámetros se verán, seguramente, perjudicados. Así, por ejemplo, muchas optimizaciones se consiguen almacenando resultados intermedios para evitar recalcularlos nuevamente ... eso consume más memoria
- Si aumentan los recursos de RAM puede que también estemos sobrecargando la memoria caché ... la repaginación de la caché suele tener como efecto principal una degradación importante en los tiempos de ejecución (el programa debe esperar a que los datos estén en la caché para poder utilizarlos)

Así que, como puedes ver, conceptos como *óptimo* o *eficiente* son engañosos y están, normalmente, mal utilizados

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta gran explicación y tan detallada he entendido varios conceptos que no tenia tan claros. Un saludo !